# What is the fastest way to read a constant, read-only dataset from compiled function?

Tags: performance-tuning, data, compile

I need a compiled function $f(\theta,\mathcal D)$ that uses some variables $\theta$ and some data $\mathcal D$. I will be calling the function multiple times with different values of the variables, but with always the same data $\mathcal D$. I am trying to make the execution of the function as fast as possible.

**Q: What is the best way to pass the data to the function to optimize the execution speed?**

---

### Attempts

Based on what I would do in other languages, I would be inclined to define the data as a constant array, and use it in the function, but I'm, not sure about how to do this in Mathematica, nor if it would actually be better.

I have tried a couple of examples:

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10^5];
f1 = Compile[{{d, _Real, 1}}, Total[d], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
f2 = Compile[{}, Total[data], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
f3 = Compile[{}, With[{d = data}, Total[d]], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

The running times, shown below, make clear that $f_1$ performs faster than $f_2$ and $f_3$.

[image]

**Some contradictions?**

Neither $f_2$ nor $f_3$ seem to compile the data inside the function, despite `data` being defined at compile time. I say this after running

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10^3];
f2[]
f3[]
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10^3];
f2[]
f3[]
```

and observing that that both calls to $f_2$ and $f_3$ after redefining the data give different results.

On the other hand, the compile times of $f_2$ and $f_3$ increase with the size of the dataset, which suggests to me that the data is being compiled into the functions:

[image]

So do $f_2$ and $f_3$ compile the data in any way? (This is not THE question, but an additional question that might be good to address to answer the main question).

Comment: `f2` and `f3` aren't able to really take advantage of anything because `data` is a global, uncompilable variable

Comment: Have you considererd using the package `<< CompiledFunctionTools` ? Then using `CompilePrint` to display what your functions are compiled. I agree with above, explore setting your function attribute to Listable. Then you could run your function over your data list.

Comment: Thanks @Shelton_swelton. Using CompilePrint on f2 and f3 shows an identical output. In both of them, the list of data points is included. What I don't understand then is why those functions are sensitive to changes of the variable `data` after compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inspect the generated code with [CCodeStringGenerate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/CCodeGenerator/ref/CCodeStringGenerate.html). And it seems that `f2` and `f3` copies data into the code, that's why the compilation is so slow, but then the code makes a call to Kernel for the fresh values each time.

Comment: You could circumvent this by using the `With[{data=data}, Compile[...]]` idiom but at that point there's barely a point to compiling in the first place since extra compilation time will swamp any downstream benefit I imagine

Comment: @b3m2a1 Compilation time is not a big issue for my specific problem. I will be calling the function many millions of times in a process that may take days. What would be the difference between With[Compile[...]] and Compile[With[...]]?

Comment: @anonymous the former injects the data into the compile statement and which is what you really wanted to do. The latter treats data like a global variable but accidentally also copies the data in

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thank you! It does work better than $f_2$ and $f_3$, and it does what I was attempting to do initially, but it is slightly (around 10%) slower than $f_1$, which still puzzles me. I would expect the fully compiled data to be the fastest, but I guess I'm wrong, or missing something.